# Mobile conditional tags for blogger responsive template

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I can use true or false statements in blogger conditional tags if I don't want to show elements in blogger mobile.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile == &quot;false&quot;'> //Contents inside this, will only appear in Desktop version. </b:if>
```

But is there any way to onactive elements in mobile phones with specific resolution; e.i: (240*320)? OR, is there any way to inactive a specific element for a lower class browser that doesn't support adsense (e.i: Opera Mini for 240*320)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native blogger tag to prevent rendering of ad for smaller screens.

But You can hide the ads in smaller screens using CSS3 media queries.

Add a unique ID or classname to the adsense ad block.

for example:

```
<div id="mobileAdsenseAds">

  // your adsense ad code here

</div>
```

In case, if you have added ads using blogger gadgets, then you can get the CSS ID by viewing the EDIT HTML tab or view source in browser.

In CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 240px) {

  /* For hiding adsense ads */
  #mobileAdsenseAds { 
     display: none; 
  }

}
```